# Proving that for a continuous function $\forall n: x_1...x_n\in(a,b):\exists x\in(a,b) \ s.t \ f(x)=\frac1n ( f(x_1)...f(x_n) ) $

Tags: calculus

> We have a continuous function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$
>
> Prove that: $\forall n: x_1...x_n\in(a,b):\exists x\in(a,b)$ such that:
>
> $$f(x)=\frac1n ( f(x_1)+...+f(x_n) ) $$

Experience tells me that it may be possible with induction but I have no clue on how to begin, I don't even see how is that possible.

Help please ?

Comment: This follows from the intermediate value theorem. Just note that the given average lies somewhere between the smallest of the $f(x_i)$, and the largest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume $x_1=\min_n x_i$ and $x_n=\max_n x_i$ and since $f$ is continuous on the compact $[x_1,x_n]$ then it's bounded and attains its extermum $m$ and $M$ hence 
$$m\le \frac1n ( f(x_1)+...+f(x_n) )\le M$$
so by the intermediate value theorem:
$$\exists x\in[x_1,x_n]\subset(a,b)\;\;|\;\; f(x)=\frac1n ( f(x_1)+...+f(x_n) )$$

Comment: How does the intermediate value theorem come into play here ? We can't know that for some x: $f(x)=0$ or that the sign changes...

Comment: As I explained in my answer $y=\frac1n ( f(x_1)+...+f(x_n) )\in [m,M]=f([x_1,x_n])$ hence by IVT there's $x\in[x_1,x_n]$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: I see now. Very elegant. Thanks.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Hello dear brother. My hat is soooo funny because it hides one of my eyes. :D

Comment: Very well done! +1

Answer (score 3):

The average of the n values of f must lie between the smallest and the biggest of those n values (you can use induction for that if you feel like it). Then use the intermediate value theorem.